# Good Resource for Embedding Weather Forecasts

Tags: embed, weather

I would like to add a 5-10 day weather forecast to a website.  I'm having trouble finding a website that provides an embed code for forecasts.  The few I've found look awful (circa 1990's).  I was just wondering if there was a halfway clean-looking solution that I might be overlooking in my endless Google searches.  Flash, iframe, anything...

I'm realizing that pulling in a weather RSS Feed might be the only clean solution, but I am not very familiar with parsing RSS feeds, so it will require a lot of labor on my end, since I'll be digging through documentation.

**I should also mention that this weather app is on it's own page.  So, bigger is better.  If I don't find one big enough, I'll just implement it into a floating window (jQuery Overlay, to be exact) instead of it's own page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Forecast.io](http://forecast.io/) offers a very slick weekly forecast [embed solution](http://blog.forecast.io/forecast-embeds/). You can also customize the colors and fonts to match your site if you like. It's fixed height, variable width.

Comment: As awesome as Forecast.io is, it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: This service isn't free anymore. I don't know if it used to be. Now it offers 1000 views for free and views after that will be charged.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? The blog post hasn't been updated, and as far as I can tell, there is no registration required to use the embed.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know where @Firze got that info. The forecast.io embed still works great.

Comment: https://darksky.net/dev 1,000 Calls Per Day for Free. Its fine if the site is not too busy.

Comment: The embed is not subject to API call limits. Notice how you don't even have to provide an API key to use it.

Answer (score 3):

[Weather Underground](http://www.wunderground.com/) is a successful weather forecasting site that cover most of the world (you don't say where you need the forecast for). They have something free called [Weather Stickers](http://wiki.wunderground.com/index.php/Weather_Stickers) which offer live feeds of the current observed weather situation. You just embed an image in your page. Like this:

[image: Click for London, United Kingdom Forecast]
<sub>(source: [wunderground.com](http://weathersticker.wunderground.com/weathersticker/big2_cond/language/www/global/stations/03772.gif))</sub>

They also offer weather forecast [XML feeds and API](http://wiki.wunderground.com/index.php/API_-_XML) but you'd need to do some work. Or they can build you a [custom site](http://www.wunderground.com/autobrand/info.asp). But you have to pay for that.

Weather.com offer [Weather Widgets](http://www.weather.com/services/weather-gadgets/?from=hp%5Ftools) which is a similar idea. You have to embed JavaScript for that so I can't show it here. Looks like they have RSS feeds, and if you [register](http://www.weather.com/services/oap.html?from=footer) you may be able to get more.

Comment: is this possible for Google search weather box; i.e https://www.google.co.in/search?q=weather+kolkata? It's generating a nicely formatted box with weather data. How to get that as iframe in html?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new interactive weather widget generator at https://weatherwidget.io/

It is free, very customizable, and the widgets it creates are fully responsive.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna have real good embedded weather software use the Weather Underground Api. The information on the Website (http://dutch.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs) is very good, with examples and has everything for your own development.

The information is based on the raw data to build your own environment around it. That means you have to build the look-and-feel, they provide the data.

And it is free!!!

Answer (score 1):

Tried all the other services above, but none of them worked on a site using HTTPS.

I found this service which worked:

http://www.booked.net/widgets/weather

Comment: I was surprised at how few of the free widgets support https. Thanks for the tip. This was the last remaining unencrypted parts on one of my websites.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a hack that enables to embed the Google weather widget, without any server-side support, see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61980631/218294